# subprocess.PIPE prevents executable from closing

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Why `subprocess.PIPE` prevents a called executable from closing.

I use the following script to call an executable file with a number of inputs:

```
import subprocess, time

CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
my_proc = subprocess.Popen("myApp.exe " + ' '.join([str(input1), str(input2), str(input3)]),
                            startupinfo=subprocess.STARTUPINFO(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

Then I monitor if the application has finished within a given time (300 seconds) and if not I just kill it. I also read the output of the application to know whether it failed in doing the required tasks.

```
proc_wait_time = 300
start_time = time.time()
sol_status = 'Fail'
while time.time() - start_time < proc_wait_time:
    if (my_proc.poll() is None):
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        try:
            sol_status = my_proc.stdout.read().replace('\r\n \r\n','')
            break
        except:
            sol_status = 'Fail'
            break
else:
    try: my_proc.kill()
    except: None
    sol_status = 'Frozen'

if sol_status in ['Fail', 'Frozen']:
    print ('Failed running my_proc')
```

As you can note from the code I need to wait for `myApp.exe` to finish, however, sometimes `myApp.exe` freezes. Since the script above is part of a loop, I need to identify such a situation (by a timer), keep track of it and kill `myApp.exe` so that the whole script doesn't get stuck!

Now, the issue is that if I use `subprocess.PIPE` (which I suppose I have to if I want read the output of the application) then `myApp.exe` doesn't close after finishing and consequently `my_proc.poll() is None` is always True.

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Are you closing your end of the pipe when you kill the app?

Comment: No, this is all in terms of `my_proc` how can I can close PIPE explicitly? Do I need to do it right after `kill()`? I always thought this is integrated in `kill`.  Also, how can that solve the issue of `my_proc.poll() is None` being True all the time?

Comment: If you aren't reading from the pipe, and the process writes more than a bufferfull (probably 4K) of data to it, then it's going to block until some buffer space is available - which never happens.

Comment: @jasonharper so would a workaround be `stdout.read()` once every while and merging that at the end?

Comment: @Mosy: Is there something in `stderr` ? What about the `returncode`? What happens if you use `subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /T /PID %i' % my_proc.pid)` instead of `my_proc.kill()` ? Pipe stdout directly into a file: `subprocess.Popen("myApp.exe, ..., stdout=open("C:/temp/whatever.log", 'w').open())`

Comment: @Maurice stderr is an empty string (''). If I push stdout to the log file, it prints the 664 lines of myApp.exe output into whatever.log, then the application closes, as it should, but this will add a step in my code in which I should load whatever.log and then process it. I guess jasonharper is right that I am getting a deadlock as the buffer is full. I wasn't aware of such an issue.

Comment: Either way it sounds like one more step for my code and I have to accept it :D

Comment: @Mosy: There was a 16K or 64K pipe buffer limit, i dont remember in detail, but that made me write all piped data on Windows into a file.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer can you please write it as an answer so I can accept it and others can find the answer in the future. of course if you have time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a pipe buffer limit/bug in case of huge amounts of data written to `subprocess.PIPE`. The easiest way to fix it is to pipe the data directly into a file:

```
_stdoutHandler = open('C:/somePath/stdout.log', 'w')
_stderrHandler = open('C:/somePath/stderr.log', 'w')

my_proc = subprocess.Popen(
    "myApp.exe " + ' '.join([str(input1), str(input2), str(input3)]),  
    stdout=_stdoutHandler, 
    stderr=_stderrHandler, 
    startupinfo=subprocess.STARTUPINFO(), 
    creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW
)
...
_stdoutHandler.close()
_stderrHandler.close()
```